# Computational Efficiency - I/O

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

If I have two queries, why does it seem the second query is more computationally efficient (just in terms of I/O) as the first:

The first query only returns eight fields, runs in 1.1sec and processes 115.6mb. The second, however, returns over a million records, but runs in just 3.4sec and only accesses 8.2mb.

I am really trying to understand writing queries more efficiently as I am beginning to use substantially larger pools of data. Thanks!

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `table1`
LIMIT
  10;
```

```
SELECT
  id
FROM
  `table1`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery is basically a columnar database (this is not exactly true, but it is a useful approximation).  That is, it stores each column separately.  So accessing one column only requires finding and reading that one column.  Accessing multiple columns requires finding all those columns and reading them -- even if you only want one value.

This is not only a function of performance.  The number of columns also determines billing. For users of other databases, it can be really surprising when:

```
select t.*
from t
limit 10;
```

ends up costing $10 or $100 because `t` is really big and wide.  But:

```
select count(id)
from t;
```

costs almost nothing at all.

As another note:  when you refer to a table multiple times in a query, you only pay for access once.  So self-joins are not more expensive than selecting directly from the table.